# How to set column size using f-String in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The Code:

```
for x in range(1, 11):
    for y in range(1, 11):
        print("{:5}".format(x * y), end = " ")
    print()
```

instead of using the .format() method I want to use f-string in this code but No idea how to set column in it.

Comment: print("{:5}"  this means column size is 5

Comment: Parametrize the column size OR just just f-string inseatd of format like the answer below says ?

Comment: @Julina357 not really, it means "print whatever using at least 5 characters, and fill with ` ` the missing ones". Check yourself the output of: `print("{:5}".format(123456789))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is pretty much the same, just leave the formatting part, i.e. everything from `:` onward, at the end:

```
for x in range(1, 11):
    for y in range(1, 11):
        print(f"{x * y:5}", end = " ")
    print()
```

Answer (score 2):

There's almost nothing to change:

```
for x in range(1, 11):
    for y in range(1, 11):
        print(f"{x*y:5}", end = " ")
    print()
```

Output:

```
    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10 
    2     4     6     8    10    12    14    16    18    20 
    3     6     9    12    15    18    21    24    27    30 
    4     8    12    16    20    24    28    32    36    40 
    5    10    15    20    25    30    35    40    45    50 
    6    12    18    24    30    36    42    48    54    60 
    7    14    21    28    35    42    49    56    63    70 
    8    16    24    32    40    48    56    64    72    80 
    9    18    27    36    45    54    63    72    81    90 
   10    20    30    40    50    60    70    80    90   100
```